# Short video of insurance salesman summoning a demon who also is into insurance

Tags: story-identification, movie, demons

I remember seeing, probably in the 90s, a short movie with a nerdy insurance salesman who decided, for reasons I can't remember, to summon a demon.

He successfully summoned two, one traditionally demonic, and another which understood a lot about insurance. I remember the summoner passed a policy through the summoning circle for that demon to check out, and after reading it briefly, he said, "Wow."

The other demon that was summoned, I think in a different summoning circle, was highly irritated at the situation of two insurance nerds, one of them demonic, obsessing over something as mundane as insurance.

The movie reminds me of the style of *Tales from the Crypt*, though I couldn't find anything that seemed like it might be the correct short. The movie was probably about 10 minutes long.

Any ideas of the series and title?

Comment: I found this from the television series "Monsters", from the late 1980s. I haven't posted this as an answer because I have not seen the episode, but the synopsis meets much of your criteria. This was a half-hour show. "A greedy alien named Arcturus tries to enslave a demon to grant his wishes, but instead gets a poor insurance agent from Chicago named Arthur Gammet. Poor Arthur must grant the alien's wishes even if it means getting a demon of his own." quote from IMDB.

Comment: Review of the above at https://www.imdb.com/review/rw4978280/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk

Comment: @StanleyWebb I knew it sounded familiar, that's a Robert Sheckley story.

Comment: That does indeed sound like what I remember, thank you! My memory, it seems, was somewhat faulty, but that's not surprising either. But now that you remind me, I recall the Arcturus alien wanted "drast", which turned out to be gold.

Comment: Do you want to view https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6vuhjw and see if it matches?

Comment: @StanleyWebb I found the episode on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWSppYvAAz8) (it may be region-locked, I can't tell); the bit with Arthur passing the demon the insurance policy and the demon saying "Wow" is at [20:20](https://youtu.be/jWSppYvAAz8?t=1220).  You should definitely post this as an answer.

Comment: @StanleyWebb: Now that there is more confirmation, if you want to add your own answer, let me know and I'll delete mine. I figured it had been a half hour, and my own research seemed to confirm it.

Comment: @fuzzyboots: Please keep your own answer posted. Thanks for verifying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As noted by Stanley Webb, this might be the 32nd episode of *Monsters* (Episode 8 of [Season 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monsters_episodes#Season_2_(1989%E2%80%9390))), "The Demons", which is an adaptation of a Robert Sheckley short story of the same name.

> A greedy extraterrestrial sorcerer named Arturus (Richard Moll) attempts to summon a demon that he will command to bring him gold (or "drast" as he calls it). By using a wrong ingredient during the summoning ritual, Arturus accidentally summons his dimensional counterpart, a work-obsessed insurance salesman named Arthur Gammet (Jeff Silverman). Despite his initial confusion, Arturus demands the just-as-confused Arthur to bring him his gold. To avoid a lifetime in a cage for failing Arturus, Arthur convinces the sorcerer to send him back to Earth to get the gold. Once he returns, Arthur decides to summon his own demon in an attempt to free himself from Arturus' control. By repeating the same mistake Arturus made, Arthur manages to summon another dimensional counterpart, a meticulous and neurotic demon named Arturo (Eddie Deezen). When Arthur and Arturo discover that they both share an enthusiastic obsession with insurance, the duo agree to work together to stop Arturus and free themselves.